# FTP using Unix shell script and then triggering a task

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have a requirement at hand in Unix where I need to build a shell script.

The requirement is below:

1. I need to SFTP a file (let's say CSV file) from my dev server to uat server.
2. After the SFTP is done to that server, as soon as the file comes there and the exit code of the previous SFTP is 0, I need to trigger a task (this task I can take care of).

I have the basic idea on SFTP but I am not aware of how to trigger the next task as soon as the file comes to the uat server.

Please need a pseudo code to start my exploration.

Comment: What kind of task you're planning to trigger? Is it a section of code/function or any other process? You can simply create a function for that task and call that function.

Comment: The task is an import task ..I have the set the code already with me.

Comment: I think that you can write a script containing just two lines: the first invokes sftp, and the second invokes the task you need to "trigger" (start) - if sftp was successful. If you are able to do it by hand at prompt, just write those two lines in a script.

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server?

Comment: @linuxfan I m very new to scripting..how can I incorporate that trigger thing..based on exit code 0 ?

Comment: @kvantour yes I do have ssh access

Comment: Something like `sftp bla bla server.bla && command_to_start bla bla`. But your question is too broad, and you should post at least what commands you need.

Comment: If you hsve ssh access, the simplest is `scp file user@server:/path/to/file && ssh user@server command /path/to/file`

Comment: @kvantour..What about the second case?

Comment: @user3901666 For second case use this based on the return code. `inputFile='/your/file/name'

while [ -f $inputFile ]
do
 trigger your task (call a function or whatever)
 exit 0
done`

Comment: @RaghavendraGupta after the file is copied to that server( uat) I want to run  a script on that server only

Comment: Store the return code in rc/variable and then check if the return code is 0, then trigger your task. `rc= $?
if [ $rc==0 ]
then 
 trigger your task (call a function or whatever)
fi`

Comment: @user3901666 The second task is done by the ssh command

Comment: @RaghavendraGupta, `[ $rc==0 ]` is always true (so long as there are no spaces in `$rc`), because it tests whether `"$rc==0"` expands to a string that is not empty. If you want `[ "$rc" = 0 ]`, the whitespace is critical. (Using `=` rather than `==` isn't required in bash, but it's good practice for portability to platforms with only a POSIX-baseline implementation of `=`)

Comment: No it won't, if the sftp commands fails to transfer the file to UAT server from dev server in this case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's true..i have corrected that already.

Comment: @RaghavendraGupta, try it. `rc=1; if [ $rc==0 ]; then echo "$rc==0 is true"; else echo "$rc==0 is false"; fi` -- output is `1==0 is true`

Comment: @user3901666, ...btw, when I had a real production-quality need for a SFTP server with detailed application-level behavior (analyzing uploads, sending notices when they were received, doing access-control for which accounts could upload to which directories based on SalesForce roles), I wrote my own with [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/). For lighter-weight needs, you might just use [`incron`](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) to run a script of your choosing when a new file's upload is complete (by waiting on `close_write` events).

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to copy from somewhere to your local machine and run a command locally**

If you have access to `ssh` then it can be done easily which I am doing it usually.

For example I have a backup file from one of my server. We can get a copy this way using `scp`

```
scp root@server:/home/weekly.sql.zip .
```

`.` means put the file with its name here on this directory I am in now

the problem with this command is that it has an interaction for getting password so to eliminate this we can install `sshpass` and use it this way:

```
sshpass -p'your-password' scp root@server:/home/weekly.sql.zip .
```

Since we are using bash and it take care of **exiting code** if you add and `&&` operator then you can add a second command so to be triggered after first command has successfully done.

```
sshpass -p'your-password' scp root@server:/home/weekly.sql.zip . && unzip weekly.sql.zip
```

First task is *copying* a file and second is to *unzip* it.

---

installing `sshpass`:

```
sudo apt install -y sshpass
```

---

**If you want to copy from your local machine to somewhere and run a command remotely**

```
sshpass -p'your-password' scp test.txt root@address:/home/ && sshpass -p'your-password' ssh root@address cat /home/test.txt
```

Which does this:

1. copy file **test.txt** to the server
2. then read it by `cat` command